# '(' expected in List function

Tags: typescript

On line 4 I get the error `'(' expected.ts(1005)`. Basically, it expects me to put a '(' somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

Code snippet:

```js
interface WordFrequencyAnalyzer {
    calculateHighestFrequency(text: string): number;
    icalculateFrequencyForWord(text: string, word: string): number;
    List<WordFrequency> calculateMostFrequentNWords(text: string, n: number): Array<WordFrequency>;
};
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is `List<WordFrequency>` meant to indicate in this code? In Typescript, the return type is written after the function (with a `:` for it to be a type annotation), but you've already done this, so it's not clear why you wrote that. Is this just a simple oversight you made when translating this interface from a language like Java?

Comment: just remove `List<WordFrequency>`, should be fine

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I indeed thought it didn't make sense either to have the List right there. I assumed it was right because I received these snippets for a coding test. Meaning I only had to implement these snippets but not change anything in it. Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/FCcQMf3.png. But I'll go ahead and move it to the end of the line as that makes more sense.

Comment: The coding example is incorrect, the type is always after the method or parameter